# Adding fadeIn transition to PIXI sprite

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I used PIXI.js (for the first time!) to set up a rendering of a rudimentary transition, where a sprite moves diagonally across the canvas. Almost half way during the transition, I am changing the texture to use another image. It works as expected. But I want to know how to get a fadeIn effect, so the change in the image does not look abrupt. Below is the code I am using (and here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webuser7/2h4ar8sv/)).

```
var stage = new PIXI.Container();
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(150, 150, rendererOptions);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81W02uGnuLL._OU01_AC_UL160_SR160,160_.png', true);
var texture2 = PIXI.Texture.fromImage('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81887k9tnQL._OU01_AC_UL160_SR160,160_.png', true);
var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
sprite.position.x = 0;
sprite.position.y = 0;
stage.addChild(sprite);

animate();

function animate() {
    if (sprite.position.x < renderer.width
        || sprite.position.y < renderer.height) {

        if (sprite.position.x == 35) {
            sprite.texture = texture2;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    sprite.position.x += 0.5;
    sprite.position.y += 0.5;
    renderer.render(stage);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you are reassigning the texture reference, this can be pretty hard to animate a fade.

If you are able to make two sprites, one for each texture, then you can manipulate the .alpha field. I forked your jsfiddle to demonstrate this:

https://jsfiddle.net/55zvq716/

**Add a second sprite to hold texture 2; Make it start with alpha = 0 (fully transparent).**

```
    var sprite2 = new PIXI.Sprite(texture2);
    sprite2.alpha = 0;
    sprite2.position.x = 0;
    sprite2.position.y = 0;
```

**Instead of swapping textures, trigger an alpha change at the desired point.**

```
    if (sprite.position.x >= 35 && sprite2.alpha < 1) {
      sprite.alpha -= .01;
      sprite2.alpha += .01;
    }
```

Comment: So the two sprites are moving together with one on top of the other, and one fades in and the other fades out simultaneously using their alphas? That works... thanks!

Comment: I am trying to render a transition that lasts for a specified amount of time. In other words, say I want the cross-fade to last for 10 seconds. I have very little experience with graphics (web or otherwise), frame rate, etc. but I would imagine there is some correlation between frame rate and the timing between each manipulation of alpha. How do I implement a timed transition, i.e. one that lasts for N seconds?